# Groupby Clause in Pandas

Tags: python, group-by, pandas

I am trying to find the GroupBy Clause (in PANDAS DATAFRAME) which can do following things.

1. InPlace Transformation.
2. Add All the Money
3. If possible then to get the Original Dataframe with Columns "A" and "Money", And not "A" as index and "Money" as column.

The input is like below.

```
dataframe = pandas.DataFrame({'A':[11,11,22,22],
                              'Cust':['C','D','C','C'],
                              'Money':np.arange(10,30,5)})
```

Now I wanted to add / subtract Money column based on Type of Cust. Like if its "C" then subtract while "D" then add and rolled to the column "A". So for this example it will be

For A as in "11" Money is "5"
For B as in "22" Money is "-45"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Starting with your example

```
In [16]: df
Out[16]: 
    A Cust  Money
0  11    C     10
1  11    D     15
2  22    C     20
3  22    C     25
```

1. Set the sign of Money based on whether Cust is C or D, as you describe.

   ```
   In [17]: df['Money'][df['Cust'] == 'C'] *= -1
   ```
2. Sum the money, grouped by the column 'A'.

   ```
   In [18]: df.groupby('A').sum()
   Out[18]: 
       Money
   A        
   11      5
   22    -45
   ```
3. Run `In [17]` again to restore your original DataFrame, intact.

Comment: The above works for me. But reversing the []s, as in ``df[df['Cust'] == 'C']['Money'] *= -1``, would edit a copy. Right?

Comment: \*Scatches head\*, I need to write something up about this as it's *confusing*. :)

Comment: Haha. When it comes to this, I still haven't really graduated from the dumb approach: "Try things until one works." If you share a write-up, I look forward to finally knowing what I'm doing.

Comment: I'm going to write something for the docs, I also need to graduate from the dumb approach (which for me is avoid mixing modifying and masks), will be cool to work out what's going on. Will let you know when it's done!

Comment: Hi Dan, Thanks for such an awesome code. Though running IN[17] step was not quite succesful. How do you do that. I am asuming we have to assign a new data frame in In[17], please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: You can perform multiplication in place using ``*=``. When you tried it, what went wrong?

Comment: I exactly followed the code till 2nd stage. Now when I run the In[17] it gives me a dataframe with only one index i.e. Money. I was hoping for something with 2 columns , 1 for the A and other for Money. Not sure what I did wrong.

Comment: I'm still not following. Can you update your question showing the input and output?

Comment: Hi Dan, Sorry for misunderstanding. Read some more on the GROUPBY and it seems that my question was partially wrong. In 2nd Step, I just wanted to get the Goupby by "A" and only 2 columns i.e. "A" and "Money". I will edit the question also.

Comment: Depending on exactly what you mean, you might want ``df.groupby('A').sum().reset_index()`` or ``df.groupby('A').transform(np.sum).reset_index()``.

Comment: You just made my day. Thanksful to everyone for sharing their brilliance.